# Can MongoDB aggregation query other documents? In other words: recursive search in mongodb's side, not client's

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dictionary, database

In the MongoDB aggregation pattern we can work on many documents and aggregate them in new data structures by sorting, filtering, removing and adding elements, in order to produce new documents to be retrieved as a query.

Suppose, for example, that I need to find the meaning of a word in a dictionary. If I find the word 'horse' in a dictionary, I'll get something like this: 'horse is an animal'. Then, I'd like to know what an animal is, so I search again in the dictionary for the meaning of 'animal'.

If I were to do it in like, python, I'd have to find the meaning of 'dog', wait for it to arrive, then read it and extract the word animal. Then I'd have to query for the meaning of 'animal', wait for it to arrive, and so on...

Is there a way to delegate this recursive task entirely to MongoDB, so I don't need to query and wait for each word? I thought 'aggregate' would solve, but it seems it can only map documents from a query into new documents, not query data from new ones

Answer (score 0):

Mongo db aggregation framework works in steps. First you select the data from collection and you apply Group, Match, Project, Sort etc., on the selected data set. Data is transformed based on operation applied on it at each step. The next step only gets the transformed data from the previous one. What you are asking requires the complete data set at each instance and that means firing query back to the data base which is not the case here.

You can use aggregation framework, when you can select the complete set or a subset of data from collection and work on it by transforming it in each step.

Comment: So it isn't possible to work on a received document and query more documents, all server side, with or without aggregation?

Comment: Check this out -> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/  . This might help.

Answer (score 0):

*Had this question myself; answering for others who find it.*

Yes, recursive search is possible using an aggregation as of MongoDB v3.2.

See [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) as well as [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/), depending on your use case.

Also check out [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) (free, downloadable GUI for any running MongoDB instance), which has a sweet aggregation builder which provides templates for each type of aggregation and debugs live against your collection data — previewing results at each step of your aggregation.   To get to the aggregation builder, go to your collection, then the *Aggregations* tab.